# MYSQL ORDER BY CASE Issue

Tags: mysql

I have a database like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id_one   |   id_two   |   timestamp_one   |   timestamp_two   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:30       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:35       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:34       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:33       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need pull all 4 rows

```
ORDER BY 'timestamp_one' if 'id_one'=27 or 
ORDER BY 'timestamp_two' if 'id_one'=27
```

This is the statement I have now:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE id_one=27 OR id_two=27 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN id_one=27 THEN timestamp_one END DESC, 
  CASE WHEN id_two=27 THEN timestamp_two END DESC
```

This works good in that is outputs this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id_one   |   id_two   |   timestamp_one   |   timestamp_two   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:30       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:34       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:33       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:35       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I need to two timestamp columns to order like they are one so it would order like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id_one   |   id_two   |   timestamp_one   |   timestamp_two   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:30       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:33       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     27     |     35     |        9:34       |        NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     35     |     27     |        NULL       |        9:35       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope this makes sense. Essentially, I am trying to have two ORDER BY columns that are specific to a WHERE condition. Then once the correct ORDER BY column is chosen for that row, it orders the ROWS by the timestamp as a whole.

Comment: Did you mean "ORDER BY 'timestamp_two' if 'id_two'=27"?

Comment: If one timestamp or the other is always `NULL`, it might be clearer to do `ORDER BY IFNULL(timestamp_one, timestamp_two)`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
SELECT id_one, id_two, timestamp_one, timestamp_two      
FROM tablename 
WHERE id_one = 27 
    OR id_two = 27 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN id_one=27 THEN timestamp_one 
        WHEN id_two=27 THEN timestamp_two 
    END DESC
```

Comment: is this mysql specific? or is this also possible for other sql databases like postgre or informix?

Comment: @emfi This should work with any database that supports conditionals - I believe both of the ones you mentioned support CASE.

Comment: what about WHEN NULL? how to consider such row?

Comment: Hey,

can someone please tell, how can I add multiple columns in one case? for Order By. I get an error while doing this

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil You would use a separate `CASE` statement for each column you want to order by.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT 
   id_one,
   id_two,
   (CASE 
      WHEN id_one=27 THEN timestamp_one
      WHEN id_two=27 THEN timestamp_two    
   END) as timestamp
FROM tablename
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE id_one=27 OR id_two=27 
ORDER BY id ASC, timestamp_one DESC
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `order_by_multiple` ORDER BY CASE WHEN custom_name='' OR custom_name is null THEN name END , CASE WHEN custom_name !='' THEN custom_name END;
```