# CASE in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I am using this ORDER BY clause in my MySQL query:

```
"ORDER BY FIELD(best_id.status, 'open', 'bekeken', 'verstuurd', 'binnen'), best_id.datum_leveren ASC
```

Works fine.

Now I would like to make an difference with sorting the rows, ASC combined with DESC. I have been trying to achieve this by change the clause to:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(best_id.status, 'open', 'bekeken', 'verstuurd', 'binnen'),
CASE WHEN best_id.status = 'binnen' THEN  best_id.datum_leveren DESC, END
ELSE best_id.datum_leveren ASC END";
```

But I can't get it tow work. What is the right way for this or is it impossible to use an CASE in the ORDER BY clause?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need 2 CASE statements; the asc or desc applies to the entire statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue

Comment: @Robert - Doesn't look like a dupe of that to me. That seems to be about choosing different columns in the same case expression with the same sort order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN best_id.status = 'binnen'
              THEN best_id.datum_leveren
            ELSE NULL
          END DESC,
          CASE
            WHEN best_id.status = 'binnen'
              THEN NULL
            ELSE best_id.datum_leveren
          END ASC
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the second `case`.  `best_id.datum_leveren asc` will suffice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - True. Having the second expression clearly mirror the first is somewhat clearer though possibly.