# Different order by in single eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have `status` in the column of the table. The status is `Open`, `On-going`, `Close`, `Drop`, `Re-open`. I also have a `datetime` field. I want to sort the `Open`, `Drop`, `Re-open` based on date, they will be sort first but will be based on date and `On-going` status after that and `close` is always on the end.

**What I already did**

```
->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, 'Open', 'Re-open', 'Drop', 'On-going', 'Close') asc")
->orderBy('submitted_date', 'desc')
```

But this will result as priority of the status so it will be sort by status first then date.

**Output That I Want**

```
-----------------------------------------
|  submitted_date   |      status       |
-----------------------------------------
|     2019-12-05    |      Re-Open      |
-----------------------------------------
|     2019-12-06    |      Open         |
-----------------------------------------
|     2019-12-06    |      Drop         |
-----------------------------------------
|     2019-12-07    |      Open         |
-----------------------------------------
|     2019-12-04    |      Close        |
-----------------------------------------
```

Raw mysql query or eloquent query is fine. Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue

Comment: I don't know if that's what I want im clueless how to apply that to what I want.

Comment: Easy. Add everything to one `orderByRaw()` call

Comment: @Pablo What do you mean?

Comment: `->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, 'Open', 'Re-open', 'Drop', 'On-going', 'Close') asc, submitted_date desc")`

Comment: @Pablo that will just do what its doing right now

Comment: I see. You will need to split the query into two and use a `union` statement to combine the results. It can get messy so I am not sure if it can be achieved with the eloquent ORM. Perhaps you can execute two queries and combine the Eloquent collections. Ex: in raw SQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/346591/10

Comment: Ohh. Is that my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve it with the following.

```
->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, 'On-going', 'Close') asc")
->orderBy('submitted_date', 'desc')
```

Comment: You mean I should remove the status that I want to be first?

Comment: Thanks. It works, I didn't know that I just need to remove them.