# MySQL query to list A-Z for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-order-by, case, where-clause

I have a database with companies in it and each company has various contact names in their own columns named

nameone
nametwo
namethree
namefour
namefive
namesix

I need to search all the names by their first letter then pull the data if the first letter matches. 
e.g. Select nameone WHERE nameone == "B".

I then need to order this by ASC e.g.
Select nameone WHERE nameone == "B" ORDER BY ASC.

e.g.
output for T would be
Tanya
Tracey
Trevor
Tom

The problem is it may be a combination of several names that match.
e.g.
Select nameone WHERE nameone == "B" OR WHERE nametwo == "B".
and as such I need to be able to order them via A-Z in the output (hope that makes sense!)

e.g.
output for T would be
Tanya  from nameone
Tracey  from nameone
Trevor  from nametwo
Tom  from namethree

I'm using Mysqli and I thought this may be possible using CASE. Below is my query.

```
// added ."%" so value becomes e.g. A% (to allow the LIKE clause and search for first letter only 
e.g. show all nameone or nametwo begining with A)
$value = $letter . "%";
// prepare query + bind values. 
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id, displayname, nameone, nametwo, namethree, namefour, namefive, 
namesix FROM companies WHERE nameone LIKE ? OR nametwo LIKE ? OR namethree LIKE ? OR namefour LIKE ? OR 
namefive LIKE ? OR namesix LIKE ? ORDER BY (CASE WHEN nameone LIKE ? THEN nameone END) ASC, (CASE 
WHEN nametwo LIKE ? THEN nametwo END) ASC, (CASE WHEN namethree LIKE ? THEN namethree END) ASC, 
(CASE WHEN namefour LIKE ? THEN namefour END) ASC, (CASE WHEN namefive LIKE ? THEN namefive END) 
ASC, (CASE WHEN namesix LIKE ? THEN namesix END) ASC');

                        if (
                        $stmt &&
                        $stmt -> bind_param('ssssssssssss', $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, 
$value, $value, $value, $value, $value, $value, $value) &&
                        $stmt -> execute() &&
                        $stmt -> store_result() &&
                        $stmt -> bind_result($id, $displayname, $nameone, $nametwo, $namethree, 
$namefour, $namefive, $namesix)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. It orders by nameone. So if for example I search for "T" it would order by nameone then if a "T" name (say tyrone) was found in nametwo, it puts it at the top of the list instead of near the bottom.

To output the data i'm using the below in a while loop

```
<?php if (strtoupper($nameone[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($nameone)."<br>";
} ?>
<?php if (strtoupper($nametwo[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($nametwo)."<br>";
} ?>                                        
<?php if (strtoupper($namethree[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($namethree)."<br>";
} ?>    
<?php if (strtoupper($namefour[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($namefour)."<br>";
} ?> 
<?php if (strtoupper($namefive[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($namefive)."<br>";
} ?>                                         
<?php if (strtoupper($namesix[0]) == strtoupper($letter)) {
echo htmlspecialchars($namesix)."<br>";
} ?>
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

#

UPDATE

Just realised, If I searched for e.g. "T" and a name called Tanya was in "nameone" column then

```
CASE WHEN nameone LIKE ? THEN nameone END
```

would be a hit and in turn would stop the query (correct??). If so, how would I combine the list of names from nameone, nametwo, namethree etc etc in the query to A-Z them?

#

UPDATE 2

To try and make it clearer. I have a table like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   nameone    |   nametwo      |   namethree      |   companyname   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Troy     |     Alice     |        jane       |     SRS LTD     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Simon    |     james     |         Trevor     |     LRP LTD     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Spike    |     Tony       |         jon     |     Jones LTD   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Luke     |     Chris      |         tom     |     LRP LTD     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I say Give me all names begining with T then A-z them?

e.g.

```
SELECT companyname, nameone, nametwo, namethree FROM companies WHERE any names 1st letter begings with T ORDER BY ASC
```

So it would output

1. Tom
2. Tony
3. Trevor
4. Troy

#

UPDATE 3

This seems to work (still testing)

```
SELECT ID, displayname, nameone, nametwo, namethree, namefour, namefive, namesix FROM kelham WHERE nameone LIKE ? OR nametwo LIKE ? OR namethree LIKE ? OR namefour LIKE ? OR namefive LIKE ? OR namesix LIKE ? ORDER BY CASE WHEN nameone LIKE ? THEN nameone WHEN nametwo LIKE ? THEN nametwo WHEN namethree LIKE ? THEN namethree WHEN namefour LIKE ? THEN namefour  WHEN namefive LIKE ? THEN namefive WHEN namesix LIKE ? THEN namesix END ASC');
```

Comment: If there is a hit in multiple columns and the results are shown in multiple columns then how or why would you sort it. This sounds confusing. See if this is same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue

Comment: hi @NawedKhan, I've updated the above to give an example. Hope this helps

Comment: why you have name one , 2 ..etc  try to do better design as one to many relation

Comment: The whole database design is flawed. Forget about sorting for a second, and remove the code of how you display the result. Just focus on the "actual" select sql query that searches and returns the result. What if in a company more than one column has a name starting with T? which name will it show. Your query is not returning a list of names. it is returning the whole table, with all columns if in any column there is a name starting with T. So the output you show in UPDATE 2 is incorrect. The table needs to be designed differently.