# Sort rows by column1 or column2 based on value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Let say I have 2 tables:

**courses**

```
| id | name         | is_sort_by_borrower |
|----|--------------|---------------------|
| 1  | Comp Science | 1                   |
| 2  | Biz Admin    | 0                   |
| 3  | Physics      | 1                   |
```

**books**

```
| id  | title  | borrower | last_borrow_date | course_id |
| --- | ------ | -------- | ---------------- | --------- |
| 1   | Book A | 523      | 11/12/19 12:33   | 1         |
| 2   | Book B | 423      | 11/15/19 12:33   | 1         |
| 3   | Book C | 401      | 10/22/19 12:33   | 1         |
```

There's a column `is_sort_by_borrower` in **courses**, I want to get a result like this

```
| course       | book_title | borrower | last_borrow_date | is_sort_by_borrower |
|--------------|------------|----------|------------------|---------------------|
| Comp Science | Book A     | 523      | 11/12/19 12:33   | 1                   |
| Comp Science | Book B     | 423      | 11/15/19 12:33   | 1                   |
| Comp Science | Book C     | 401      | 10/22/19 12:33   | 1                   |
| Comp Science | Book D     | 377      | 11/19/19 12:33   | 1                   |
| Biz Admin    | Book E     | 122      | 11/20/19 12:33   | 0                   |
| Biz Admin    | Book F     | 419      | 11/12/19 12:33   | 0                   |
| Biz Admin    | Book G     | 65       | 10/18/19 12:33   | 0                   |
| Physics      | Book H     | 446      | 8/31/19 12:33    | 1                   |
| Physics      | Book I     | 398      | 11/2/19 12:33    | 1                   |
| Physics      | Book J     | 376      | 9/30/19 12:33    | 1                   |
| Physics      | Book K     | 249      | 10/11/19 12:33   | 1                   |
```

Is it possible to sort the result some by `borrower`, some by `last_borrow_date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create another column in the SELECT and use CASE to populate it with the value you want, then sort by that. You can also use the CASE statement in the WHERE clause, depending on if you want the sorting column to show the result or not.

ref: [MYSQL ORDER BY CASE Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue)

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

In your example:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.name, c.is_sort_by_borrower, 
    b.id, b.title, b.borrower, b.last_borrow_date
FROM
    courses c
INNER JOIN
    books b on b.course_id = c.id
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN is_sort_by_borrower=1 THEN borrower
        WHEN is_sort_by_borrower=0 THEN last_borrow_date 
    END ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. what if I want `borrower` to be **DESC**, and `last_borrow_date` to be **ASC** ?

Comment: When you mix data types in one column then MySQL might, for example, treat all dates starting with `11/` as equal. Have not tested this though.

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` needs to look like:

```
ORDER BY course -- courses grouped together
       , CASE WHEN is_sort_by_borrower = 1 THEN borrower END DESC
       , CASE WHEN is_sort_by_borrower = 0 THEN last_borrow_date END DESC
```

Exactly one of the two columns will be NULL for a given course depending on the sort flag. You must not combine the two datatypes in same column otherwise result will be unpredictable.