# sorting with multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

in my table, I have 3  timestamp columns: A,B,C.
by default their value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
I want to search and sort data by checking column C.
if column C has default data, checking  B and if B has default data checking C on that row.

how can i write mysql query?

Comment: Sample data would really help your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL ORDER BY CASE Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue)