# Conditionally ORDER BY (column value)?

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help me out with my little question. I'm looking for a way to `SELECT` my products and first show the nearest products within 30km using `ORDER BY distance ASC` and if the distance is more than 30km to `ORDER BY id DESC`.

I'm currently selecting my products using:

```
SELECT id FROM products ORDER BY distance ASC, id DESC
```

This is my products table:

```
id | distance
1  | 30
2  | 24
3  | 83
4  | 102
5  | 16
6  | 8
7  | 4
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346823/mysql-order-by-case-issue is a useful thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to have only two groups: closer than 30km and all others, you can use a kind of:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY (distance>30) ASC, id DESC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivzEhYfsTDRfyeh9mfeYBW/0

If you'd like to sort by distance within 30 km only:

```sql
SELECT products.*
FROM products 
ORDER BY least(distance, 31) ASC, id DESC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivzEhYfsTDRfyeh9mfeYBW/1

Comment: BTW, I added another option, so you can vote up for it ;)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I don't have enough reputation for vote yet, I just registered in SO, but once I have I'll vote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` to make values 30+ all be treated the same.

```sql
SELECT
    id
FROM products
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN distance < 30
        THEN distance
        ELSE 31
    END ASC,
    id DESC
```